# Responsive CSS issues on my shop

Tags: css, responsive-design, prestashop

I have some responsive issues on my prestashop site on the top menu block.
Can you please help me solve them?

On media width 500px:
- The height of the categories on the top menu are too high, the "Novedades" item cannot be seen.

On media width 600px:
- The menu subcategories are dropped down automatically by themselves.

On media width 1000px:
- The cloud on "Novedades" item is not set correctly must be a little higher.

Here is the code

```
/*** ESSENTIAL STYLES ***/
.sf-contener {
clear: both;
}
.sf-right {
  margin-right: 14px;
  float: right;
  width: 7px;
}
.sf-menu, .sf-menu * {
margin: 0;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
list-style: none;
}
.sf-menu {
margin: 10px 0;
padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
width:980px;/* 980 */
background: #383838;
/*  @media (max-width: 450px) {
    .sf-menu {
      display: none; }    */
}
.sf-menu ul {
position: absolute;
top: -999em;
width: 10em; /* left offset of submenus need to match (see below) */
}
.sf-menu ul li {
width: 100%;
}
.sf-menu li:hover {
visibility: inherit; /* fixes IE7 'sticky bug' */
}
.sf-menu li {
float: left;
position: relative;
top: 0;
/*border-right: 1px solid #777;*/
}
.sf-menu a {
display: block;
position: relative;
color:#fff;
}
.sf-menu li:hover ul,
.sf-menu li.sfHover ul {
left: 0;
/*padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;*/
top: 35px; /* match top ul list item height */
z-index: 99;
width:auto;
}
ul.sf-menu li:hover li ul,
ul.sf-menu li.sfHover li ul {
top: -999em;
}
ul.sf-menu li li:hover ul,
ul.sf-menu li li.sfHover ul {
left: 200px; /* match ul width */
top: 0;
}
ul.sf-menu li li:hover li ul,
ul.sf-menu li li.sfHover li ul {
left: 200px; /* match ul width */
top: 0;
}
ul.sf-menu li li li:hover ul,
ul.sf-menu li li li.sfHover ul {
left: 200px; /* match ul width */
top: 0;
}


/*** DEMO SKIN ***/
.cat-title {
display: none;
}
.sf-menu {
float: left;
margin-bottom: -2em;
width: 100%;
height: 75px;
background: url('http://www.dulcewashitape.com/themes/dulcewashitape/img/cabecera.png') repeat left center; 

}
.sf-menu a {
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  display:block;
    margin-right:2px;
    padding: 0 22px 0 20px;
    line-height:35px;   
    border: 10;
    text-decoration:none; 
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family:Handlee;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.sf-menu a, .sf-menu a:visited  { /* visited pseudo selector so IE6 applies text colour*/
color: #916e6e;
white-space:nowrap;
}
.sf-menu li ul {
  border:1px solid #f1b6b1; box-shadow:2px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  width:500px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 23px 0px 0px 0px;
  top:0;
  background: white;
}
.sf-menu li li {
background: white; 
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  height:35px; 
  line-height:35px; 
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;

}
.sf-menu li li a {
font-size: 16px;
text-transform: capitalize;
top:0;  
}
.sf-menu li li li {
background: white;
width:140px;
}
.sf-menu a:focus, .sf-menu a:hover, .sf-menu a:active {
   font-weight: bold; 
   color: white;
   background: url('http://www.dulcewashitape.com/themes/dulcewashitape/img/boton-b.png') no-repeat center 0px; 
}
.sf-menu ul li:hover, .sf-menu ul li.sfHover,
.sf-menu ul li a:focus, .sf-menu ul li a:hover, .sf-menu ul li a:active {
background: #eecfd0; //#4e4e4e; 
outline: 0;
} 
/*** arrows **/
.sf-menu a.sf-with-ul {
padding-right:  2.25em;
min-width: 1px; /* trigger IE7 hasLayout so spans position accurately */
padding-top: 20px;
margin-top: -20px;
}
.sf-sub-indicator {
position: absolute;
display: block;
right: 10px;
top: 1.05em; /* IE6 only */
width: 10px;
height: 35px;
text-indent:  -999em;
overflow: hidden;
background: url('../img/arrows-ffffff.png') no-repeat -10px -100px; /* 8-bit indexed alpha png. IE6 gets solid image only */
}
a > .sf-sub-indicator {  /* give all except IE6 the correct values */
top: 11px;
background-position: 0 -100px; /* use translucent arrow for modern browsers*/
}
/* apply hovers to modern browsers */
a:focus > .sf-sub-indicator,
a:hover > .sf-sub-indicator,
a:active > .sf-sub-indicator,
li:hover > a > .sf-sub-indicator,
li.sfHover > a > .sf-sub-indicator {
background-position: -10px -100px; /* arrow hovers for modern browsers*/
}


/* point right for anchors in subs */
.sf-menu ul .sf-sub-indicator { background-position:  -10px 0; }
.sf-menu ul a > .sf-sub-indicator { background-position:  0 0; }
/* apply hovers to modern browsers */
.sf-menu ul a:focus > .sf-sub-indicator,
.sf-menu ul a:hover > .sf-sub-indicator,
.sf-menu ul a:active > .sf-sub-indicator,
.sf-menu ul li:hover > a > .sf-sub-indicator,
.sf-menu ul li.sfHover > a > .sf-sub-indicator {
background-position: -10px 0; /* arrow hovers for modern browsers*/
}


/*** shadows for all but IE6 ***/
.sf-shadow ul {
background: url('../img/shadow.png') no-repeat bottom right;
padding: 0 8px 9px 0;
-moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 17px;
-moz-border-top-right-radius: 17px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 17px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 17px;
}
.sf-shadow ul.sf-shadow-off {
background: transparent;
}
li.sf-search {
  background: inherit;
  float: right;
  line-height: 25px;
  background:transparent;
}
li.sf-search input {
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  margin: 18px 6px 0 0;
  background: #fff url('../../../../img/search-zoom3.png') no-repeat left center;
  border:1px solid #777;
}


/* hack IE7 */
.sf-menu a, .sf-menu a:visited {height:34px !IE;}
.sf-menu li li {
width:200px;
background:#726f72 !IE;
}

#block_top_menu .category-thumbnail {
  display:none;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  float: none; }
  #block_top_menu .category-thumbnail div {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33333%; }
    #block_top_menu .category-thumbnail div img {
      max-width: 100%; }
#block_top_menu li.category-thumbnail {
  padding-right: 0; }




/* Mobile Item */
.sf-menu-phone-item { display:none; }
#sf-menu-phone-trigger { display:none; position:absolute; top:7px; right:0; background:url('http://www.dulcewashitape.com/themes/dulcewashitape/img/icon-mobile-nav.png') top right no-repeat #29addd; width:50px; height:50px; text-indent:-9999px; border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0s; }
#sf-menu-phone-trigger:hover { background-color:#333; }
#sf-menu-phone-trigger.active { background-position:bottom right; }

@media only screen and (max-width: 999px) {
    .sf-menu a, .sf-menu a:visited  {font-size:13px;}
}
/* Tablet Only Queries */
@media only screen and (min-width: 531px) and (max-width: 786px)  { 
    .sf-menu a, .sf-menu a:visited  {font-size:12px;}
}

/* Phone Only Queries */
@media only screen and (max-width: 530px) { 
    #sf-menu-header {height:auto; }
    #sf-menu-top-nav {margin-left:-2%; margin-right:-2%;}
    /*.sf-menu {display:none; } */
    .sf-menu {width:100%; height:auto; margin:10px 0 0 0; position:static !important}
    .sf-menu li {width:100%; background:#f4f4f4;  border-top:1px solid #fff !important; border-bottom:1px solid #999 !important; -webkit-border-radius:0; border-radius:0; }
    .sf-menu li:hover {background:#de8686;}
    .sf-menu li ul {width:100%; position:static !important; background:#ccc;}
    .sf-menu li li {width:100% !important; background:#ccc; }
    /*.sf-menu li li li {display:none !important;}*/
    .sf-menu-phone-item { display:block; }
    #sf-menu-phone-trigger { display:block; }
    .sf-search {padding:10px;} 
    #searchbox {margin-left:15px;}
    #searchbox input[type="text"] {width:80%;}
    #searchbox input[type="text"]:focus, #searchbox input[type="text"]:hover {width:80%;}
    #searchbox .button {width:10%;}
    #header_logo { padding-right:50px; text-align:left !important;}
}
```

And the site is : [www.dulcewashitape.com][1]

Thank you very much I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

**On media width 1000px:** The "Washi Tape" text is reading the CSS for the `a.sf-with-ul` class whereas the "Novedades" is executing the CSS for `a`, and they have differing CSS values.

Take the CSS in `a.sf-with-ul` and apply it to the `a` to align your clouds:

```
ul.sf-menu li a {
  padding-right: 2.25em;
  min-width: 1px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  margin-top: -20px;
}
```

**On media width 500px:** You have a `top:20px;` that pushes your text down assigned inside `.sf-menu a`. Removing it is not an option since it causes misalignment at higher screen widths to your menu. Given this constraint, you can create a special rule using the following to only apply your desired `top:5px;` if the screen width is less than or equal to 500px

```
@media screen (max-width: 500px) {
  .sf-menu a{
    top:5px;
  }
}
```

Unfortunately I do now know how to fix the automatically dropping down menu, goodluck!

Comment: Thanks for your help. The 1000px issue is solved!
However I do not know how to apply the 500px as if I do it as I understand you told me, on higher resolutions still goes wrong and the height of each subcategories is bigger than it should.

Comment: Just I saw that the solution of the first issues is causing the troubles to the height of the subcategories, removing the solution and apply only solution of 500px solved the issue for 500px devices.

Comment: I can't access your website any longer since you have a splash page instead of the index. Try adding `ul.sf-menu li a{top:20px;}` to the `max-width:500px;`